# C4Shape Custom Subclass init issues?

Tags: ios, c4

I've asked another question regarding this project before and Travis was super helpful. [Previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16328896/gesture-controls-crash-when-calling-methods-on-c4workspace-m)

Taking that advice into mind I'm trying to create a subclass for the C4Shape class, I added 2 properties (both floats) to the class for X and Y position values. The reason I'm not just calling the .center property of a C4Shape is because for adding them to the canvas I prefer to use the top left corner instead of the center.

I'm trying to write a custom Init method for this new class, however I'm getting an error.

Here is the custom init code I'm working with:

customShape.m

```
- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)fillColor atX:(float)_xValue atY:(float)_yValue
{
CGRect frame = CGRectMake(_xValue, _yValue, 100, 100);
self = [customShape rect:frame];

self.lineWidth = 0.0f;
self.fillColor = fillColor;
self.xValue = _xValue;
self.yValue = _yValue;


return self;
}
```

C4WorkSpace.m

```
-(void)setup {
customShape *testShape = [[customShape alloc]initWithColor:[UIColor greenColor] atX:50.0f atY:50.0f];

[self.canvas addShape:testShape];
}
```

I suspect the culprit is `self = [customShape rect:frame];` This is the warning I see: "Incompatible pointer type assigning to 'customeShape *_strong' from 'C4Shape *'"

The actual error that gets thrown when I try to run this is: "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[C4Shape setXValue:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x9812580'"

As before I'm making buttons that can hold a color value and when you tap that button it will send a UDP packet with that buttons fillColor as well as the iPads IP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're quite close with the implementation of your init method. I would restructure it in the following way:

```
- (id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)aColor origin:(CGPoint)aPoint {
    self = [super init];
    if(self != nil) {
        CGRect frame = CGRectMake(0,0, 100, 100);
        [self rect:frame];
        self.lineWidth = 0.0f;
        self.fillColor = aColor;
        self.origin = aPoint;
    }
    return self;
}
```

A couple things to note:

1. When subclassing it's always good to call the init method of the object's superclass
2. It's good practice to wrap the `init` of your subclass in an `if` statement, checking to see if the super class init returned properly.
3. Create a frame for your new object and call `rect:` on `self` directly.
4. There is an `origin` point in every visible C4 object, so instead of using `x` and `y` values directly, you can set the origin with a `CGPoint` (the `origin` is the top-left corner).

You then need to add this method to your `.h` file:

```
@interface MyShape : C4Shape
-(id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)aColor origin:(CGPoint)aPoint;
@end
```

Finally, you can create your shape in your `C4WorkSpace` like this:

```
MyShape *m = [[MyShape alloc] initWithColor:[UIColor darkGrayColor]
                                     origin:CGPointMake(100, 100)];
```

And, if you add a line to your tapped method you can check the origin point of the button:

```
-(void)heardTap:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    MyShape *notificationShape = (MyShape *)[aNotification object];
    C4Log(@"%4.2f,%4.2f",notificationShape.center.x,notificationShape.center.y);
    C4Log(@"%4.2f,%4.2f",notificationShape.origin.x,notificationShape.origin.y);
    C4Log(@"%@",notificationShape.strokeColor);
}
```

---

While you can work with `x` and `y` values as properties, I recommend working with `CGPoint` structures. It's almost the same, except as you progress from C4 into Objective-C you'll notice that `CGPoint` and other `CG` geometry structures are used *everywhere*.

Comment: No problem! Keep the questions coming.